# How to create condition for html selector with .each Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors

Cycle displays several checkboxes and labels.
After 5, rest of checkboxes should be displayed under one `.for-disable` class.

How to do it in a loop?

*My .each method in haml:*

```
- @interests.each do |interest|
  %li
    = f.check_box(interest.id)
    = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)
```

*I tried:*

```
- @interests.each do |interest|
    - if interest.id == 5
      .for-disable
        %li
          = f.check_box(interest.id)
          = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)
    - else
      %li
        = f.check_box(interest.id)
        = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)
```

But, as expected, in this case only one checkbox is displayed in the 'for-disable' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important note: adding a `div` as a child of an `ul` is [invalid HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) :)**

As an alternative, you could add the `for-disable` class added to the `li`s after the first five `interests`?

How about this using [`each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index):

```
- @interests.each_with_index do |interest, index|
  %li{ class: ("for-disable" if index > 4) }
    = f.check_box(interest.id)
    = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)
```

Or an alternative syntax using the [`tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/tag) helper should you prefer it:

```
- @interests.each_with_index do |interest, index|
  = tag.li class: ("for-disable" if index > 4) do
    = f.check_box(interest.id)
    = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)
```

The index starts at `0`, hence checking if `> 4`.

---

Alternatively, if you want all `interests` after the first five in a separate `div` you could use:

```
%ul
  - @interests.first(5) do |interest|
    %li
      = f.check_box(interest.id)
      = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)

.for-disable
  %ul
    - @interests.drop(5) do |interest|
      %li
        = f.check_box(interest.id)
        = f.label(interest.id, interest.name)
```

---

Both nice and clean and should offer something to do what you're after - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help @РоманОкс - which approach did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote helper for this. You can use this helper:

1. Add these helper methods to `interests_helper.rb` or anywhere you want.

   ```
   def checkboxes(interests, form)
     container = ''
     for_disable_div = '<div class="for-disable">'
     interests.each do |interest|
       if interest.id > 5
         for_disable_div += checkbox_item(interest, form)
       else
         container += checkbox_item(interest, form)
       end
     end
     sanitize "#{container} #{for_disable_div}</div>"
   end

   def checkbox_item(interest, form)
     content_tag :li do
       form.check_box(interest.id)
       form.label(interest.id, interest.name)
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use it in form

   ```
   = checkboxes(interests, f)
   ```

Comment: This still has the problem that of invalid HTML in a UL.